# h:selectOneMenu value should change onclick of p:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a problem in my application.

I have a datatable, inside that one selectBooleancheckbox , selectonemenu with items("Confirmed", "Rejected" ,"selected") and one inputText is there. I need to write code for,

if selectbooleancheckbox is checked then the selectonemenu will get the value "Selected" and the inputText also become editable.

this is my xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable id="panel1"
             rendered="true"
             var="step2table"
             value="#{dtstep2_tab1.step2table}"
             editMode="cell"
             scrollable="true"
             selection="#{dtstep2_tab1.selectedrows}"
             rowKey="#{step2table.rs2_empname}"
             rowSelectMode="checkbox"
             rowStatePreserved="true">

    <p:column headerText="Select" id="hSelect" style="font-size:12px;width:60px;">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="Booleanchkbox" >

            <p:ajax listener="#{dtstep2_tab1.UpdateStatus}" update="panel1" />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Status" id="hStatus" style="font-size:12px;width:100px;">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="cbo" value="#{step2table.rs2_status}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Confirmed" itemValue="Confirmed"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selected" itemValue="Selected"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Rejected" itemValue="Rejected"></f:selectItem>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="font-size:12px;width:150px;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Comments"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>

        <h:inputText value="#{step2table.rs2_comments}" rendered="#{dtstep2_tab1.editable}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and in bean I have the following code in addition with getter and setter method.

```
public void UpdateStatus(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    SelectBooleanCheckbox permit = (SelectBooleanCheckbox) event.getComponent();
    boolean checked = (Boolean) permit.getValue();

    if (checked) {
        setRs2_status("Selected");
        setEditable(true);
        setSelect(true);

    }
    else
        {
          setEditable(false);
          setSelect(false);
        } 

}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please guide me on the issue.

Comment: splitted as two posts. thanks

Comment: First of all, I think you're mixing JS methods with Bean methods.
`<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="Booleanchkbox" onclick="{dtstep2_tab1.select='true'}">`. You must put JS code here.
    `<p:ajax listener="#{dtstep2_tab1.UpdateStatus}" update="panel1" />`You must put a bean's method here.

Comment: FYI : The event handler `onclick` is not defined for `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

Comment: as suggested removed js method from the coding.

Comment: solved this by using row editor